# How to know the tag name is tensorflow saved model?

Tags: tensorflow

How to know the tag name is “`vgg16`” in tensorflow. Is there any way to fetch it back from the saved model graph/variable dumps?

```
tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [“vgg16”], “./data/vgg/”)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `saved_model_cli` command line tool to dump all the metadata stored in a model on disk. The tool is included with recent versions of TensorFlow (1.4+ for sure) when you `pip install` it.

For example:

```
saved_model_cli show --dir ./data/vgg --all
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, just a correction show should come before dir switch. 
    saved_model_cli show --dir ./data/vgg